# TextView without partially drawn lines

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

Would it be possible to create a TextView in Android that can scroll many lines of text, but will not draw the first or last line of text unless it can be drawn in it's height completely? I realize that it might look strange when scrolling, but I don't want to see the cut-off tops or bottoms of characters.

The suggested solution may involve modifying the android platform.

Comment: U want the textView to scroll line by line, not smoothly...?

Comment: Yes, line by line or by pages but yeah no smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by modifying the android platform, but there is no restriction in coding your own TextView (or extending android TextView to change the scrolling) if you want a completely new behavior.

If you really want to do this, you could change the Touch/Scrolll behavior to directly scroll to the next/previous visible line try changing the TextView Scoller (`setScoller( )` method). If that doesn't work, you will have to code your own (basically getting the line position by `textview.getLayout().getLineTop(line number)` and positioning the screen top to that point).

The only restriction you have is when you need to change something that is embedded within the “kernel” (like, for example, a media protocol from MediaPlayer).

Check this [marquee example](http://bear-polka.blogspot.com/2009/01/scrolltextview-scrolling-textview-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod.html  along with the scroller. Your textView height needs to be a multiple of your text line height.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, I would advise you to use the [WheelView by Yuri](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

If you choose your a good combination of background, height, and width; you will get the effect that you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Terminal Emulator project includes a library with an EmulatorView class that behaves pretty much the way I want and is open source: https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator

It contains a fair amount of extra code for terminal stuff though but that could be stripped out probably if necessary. However I must assume that it supports only monospace fonts which makes it less useful.